# Windows C++ Filter Sound Output

Tags: c++, windows, api, audio, filter

I'm thinking of writing a C++ application for windows which would need to filter all sound output from all applications and change it.

I only have moderate experience with C++ and programming for windows and I realise that it will be a bit of a learning curve.

What sound apis would be recommended to accomplish this? If anyone has other advice about going about this, I would appreciate it!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is my understanding that Windows Vista and later may have ways you can do this, but I am not familiar with it, or if it is even usable for what you need.

Generally, the only way to do this is to create a virtual sound card driver that your applications send their audio data to.  From there, you will need a userland application that plays back that audio out of a different sound device.

You can either license [an existing virtual sound card driver](http://stereomixplus.com/), or write your own (very difficult).